# How to send dict in Header as value to key 'Authorization' in python requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have to test the results of the API. I am sending

```
Key - 'Authorization'
value - { "merchantIp": "13.130.189.149", "merchantHash": "c8b71ea1ab250adfc67f90938750cd30" , "merchantName": "test"}
```

I am getting proper output in postman but my code fails in requests

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

def main():
    url = "http://test.example.com/recharger-api/merchant/getPlanList?circleid=1&operatorid=1&categoryid=1"
    headers = {'Authorization': { "merchantIp": "13.130.189.149", "merchantHash": "c8b71ea1ab250adfc67f90938750cd30" , "merchantName": "test"}}
    response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    data = response.json()
    pprint(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I get:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader: Value for header {'Authorization': { "merchantIp": "13.130.189.149", "merchantHash": "c8b71ea1ab250adfc67f90938750cd30" , "merchantName": "test"}} must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Presumably this is is the [CY.SEND mobile recharge API](https://www.cysend.com/merchant/en/b2b-mobile-recharge-api) or a similar service? Including a link to the API documentation would let me help you much better, because then we can confirm any hypothesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The header is almost certainly expecting *JSON* data. A Python dictionary, even simply converted to a string, is not the same thing as JSON. The `requests` library doesn't accept anything other than strings for headers anyway. POSTMan only deals in strings, not Python objects, so you wouldn't see the issue there.

Explicitly convert it:

```
import json

headers = {
    'Authorization': json.dumps({
        "merchantIp": "13.130.189.149",
        "merchantHash": "c8b71ea1ab250adfc67f90938750cd30",
        "merchantName": "test"
    })
}
```